# Deciding on unit test code coverage for higher level methods

Tags: c#, unit-testing

When I have a method like below,

```
double Process(double payable)
{
    var step1Result = Step1(payable);
    var step2Result = Step2(step1Result);
    return Step3(step2Result);
}
```

is it required to have a unit test for Process() when I already have unit tests for the inner three public methods?
If the answer is not required, then does it mean that the Process() method has to be maintained through manual code review?

Comment: Your question has been answered here: http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/188609/best-way-to-unit-test-methods-that-call-other-methods-inside-same-class

Comment: This is my opinion. The fact that it is my **opinion** is also the reason why I co-voted to close the question as "primarily opinion-based". Anyway, my opinion is this. Do you care about the method? No? Then don't bother testing it. Yes? Then obviously you should test it. Why? Because you're not only testing the **current** implementation, you're also safe-guarding against **future changes**. Don't fall into the trap of thinking "The current code works, why do I need to test working code?".

Answer (score 1):

If Process is public then Yes, you will need unit tests for Process. If someone is fixing a bug and forgets to call Step2, Process will not work anymore. If you have written code, it has to be tested.

If it is not public, then as long as it is being covered via some other method calling it, for example, another public method then you should be fine. Basically if the Process method is being used and you put a breakpoint and run all your tests and it does not hit the breakpoint, then that means it is not covered and tested. Of course you can use visual studio's test coverage to indicate if it is covered instead of using a breakpoint.